# Java Static Class Variable

Tags: java, class, static

I'm struggling to figure out why the below Java code has the following output.

Specifically, why does the value of s get set to 125 each time and the value of ns get set to 0 for ref3?

**Code**

```
public class App {

  int ns;
  static int s;

  App (int ns) {
    if (s < ns) {
      s = ns;
      this.ns = ns;
    }
  }

  void doPrint () {
    System.out.println("ns = " + ns + ", s = " + s);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    App ref1 = new App(50);
    App ref2 = new App(125);
    App ref3 = new App(100);

    ref1.doPrint();
    ref2.doPrint();
    ref3.doPrint();
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
ns = 50, s = 125
ns = 125, s = 125
ns = 0, s = 125
```

Comment: 100 is less than 125, so your `if` is false and the assignments are not executed (and `ns` stays at the initial default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different aspects that come into play.

#### Default values

Variables in Java have default values, even if you don't specify them. For `int` this is `0`, so the initial values of your `App` class are:

```
int ns = 0;
static int s = 0;
```

So actually `ns` is not "set to 0 for ref3", but instead just keeps its initial value, whereas `ref1` and `ref2` explicitly alter the value.

#### Variable scopes

Let's look at the constructor of `App`:

```
App (int ns) {
  if (s < ns) {
    s = ns;
    this.ns = ns;
  }
}
```

There are two different variables with the name `ns`:

- `this.ns`, which references the field on instance level (which at this point still has its initial value `0`)
- `ns` (without `this`), which is only visible inside the constructor and has the value provided via the constructor argument (`50`, `125` or `100`).

#### Static variables

`s` is a static variable and associated with the `App` class itself, not with a specific instance. So whenever one instance changes its value (e.g. because `50 < 125` in the constructor), all other instances (in fact: the entire program) will see the updated value.

The logic inside the constructor basically sets `s` to the maximum of all provided `ns` values so far, which is in this case `125`. Try to move your `doPrint()` methods a few lines above and see how those values change.

#### Appendix: "Debugging"

For a complete overview of how the values evolve you can also add some "debug" statements:

```
System.out.println("App.s=" + App.s);
App ref1 = new App(50);
System.out.println("ref1.ns=" + ref1.ns + ", ref1.s=" + ref1.s + ", App.s=" + App.s);
App ref2 = new App(125);
System.out.println("ref2.ns=" + ref2.ns + ", ref2.s=" + ref2.s + ", App.s=" + App.s);
App ref3 = new App(100);
System.out.println("ref3.ns=" + ref3.ns + ", ref3.s=" + ref3.s + ", App.s=" + App.s);
```

This will output:

```
App.s=0
ref1.ns=50, ref1.s=50, App.s=50
ref2.ns=125, ref2.s=125, App.s=125
ref3.ns=0, ref3.s=125, App.s=125
```

You can see that `ref.s` is always equals `App.s` and `App.s` exists even before you create your first instance.

Answer (score 2):

`ns` is set when `s < ns`,

for `ref1` you pass `ns` = `50`, but `s` is uninitialized and java assumes `s` as zero, so it enters `if ( s < ns )` and sets `ref1`'s class variable `ns` and also static `ns`to `50`

for `ref2` you pass `ns` = `125` but `s` is 50, `if( s < ns )` holds true, so enters if and updates static variable `s` to 125 and `ref2`'s class variable `ns` to 125

for `ref3` you pass `ns` = `100`, but `s` is already `125` and hence doesn't enter if condition, there `ns` stays uninitialized whose value is zero when printed.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, when a variable is declared with the keyword “static”, its called a “class variable”. All instances share the same copy of the variable.

So when `App ref2 = new App(125)` has run, `s` is `125`. And in `App ref3 = new App(100)`, `ns` is `100`, leee than `s (125)`, so your if assignments are not executed, which mean `ns` stays at the initial default `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Static in Java roughly means that a variable is shared between all class instances (and class itself). It is initialized before everything else, and when you update it in one instance it's reflected in all other instances.

Your program's execution is as follows:

- Initialize s to 0 (default int)
- 0 < 50 therefore set both to 50
- 50 < 125 therefore set both to 125
- 125 > 100 therefore don't execute if branch. ns is uninitialized at the end of constructor, so it gets initialized to 0 by default

Also, you are printing values after that steps, so our unique s is bound to 125

Answer (score 0):

The value of `s` gets to 125 each time because it is a **static variable** and static variables are common to the class so their values do not change for every object that you create.As you call the `doPrint` method after all the object creations so the recent value of s is **125** and so is your output for every call to the `doPrint` method.

The value of `ns` is set to 0 for `ref3` beacause in your constructor you are comparing  `s` and `ns` .When you create reference variable `ref3` this happens  in the constructor:

```
    `App (int ns) 
     {
      if (s < ns)   /* s is 125 and ns is 100 so the if statement evaluates 
                     to  false and the assignments don't happen*/
     {
     s = ns;        // this isn't performed
     this.ns = ns;  // even this isn't performed
     }
    }`
```

So when you call `ref3.doPrint()` value of `ns` is **0** and `s` is **125** and so is your output .